# CCRenderTexture (alpha) beginWithClear transparent white

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I don`t understand how transparency/alpa works with CCRenderTexture.

With this code i would have expected a half transparent white over the red ColorLayer (Transparency works for the CCLayerColor). What i get is complete white.

This Code is just added to the default Template at the end of the HelloWorldLayer init Method.

```
    CCLayerColor * lc = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 125.0f)];
    [self addChild:lc];

    CCRenderTexture * rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:480.0f
                                                            height:320.0f];
    [self addChild:rt];
    rt.position = ccp(240.0f,160.0f);

    [rt beginWithClear:1.0f g:1.0f b:1.0f a:0.5f];

    [rt end];
```

if i change to black i DO get half transparent black:

```
    [rt beginWithClear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:0.5f];
```

With alpha 0.0f and green 1.0 i get green - would have expected a clear layer..
        [rt beginWithClear:0.0f g:1.0f b:0.0f a:0.0f];

The real problem ist that in that RT i can`t draw transparency with white in a fragment shader:

```
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);
```

results in complete white..

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
[renderTexture.sprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}];
```